# Haskell example where pure and return not interchangeable

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative

Is Haskell's `pure` function the same as `return`?

I just can make a type an instance of Monad if it is already an instance of Applicative, right? So I wonder that Applicative's  `pure` is everytime interchangeable with Monad's `return`?
Is there an example where they are not the same?

```
data HelloType a = HelloType { getValue :: a } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Functor HelloType where
    fmap f (HelloType y) = HelloType (f y)

instance Applicative HelloType where
    (<*>) (HelloType f) (HelloType x) = HelloType (f x)
    pure = HelloType

instance Monad HelloType where
    (>>=) (HelloType x) f = f x
    -- return = pure
    return = HelloType

plus3 :: (Num a) => Maybe a -> HelloType (Maybe a)
plus3 (Just x) = HelloType (Just $ x + 3)
plus3 Nothing = HelloType Nothing

main= do
    let withPure = pure (Just 3) >>= plus3 >>= plus3
        withReturn = return (Just 3) >>= plus3 >>= plus3
    print $ withPure == withReturn -- TRUE
```

Comment: Every type that is an instance of `Monad` must have its `return` equal to `pure`. But there are types which are `Applicative` but not a `Monad`, and therefore have a `pure` but no `return`. `ZipList` is the traditional example here.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you for this fast reply!
Is it unconventional to just use pure in larger Haskell projects? So to never define return for Monad instances?

If you would like to add your first comment as an answer, I can mark this question as resolved.

Comment: unfortunately I'm pretty new to Haskell, so I can't speak for what people do in "larger Haskell projects". (Although I'm sure some of the other regular contributors here can help you on this.) Personally I like to use `return` if I'm working in the context of a `Monad` (for example, a `do` block) but just use `pure` if I happen to need the function "on the fly" (to embed an element in a singleton list, typically). But I don't really know what the idiomatic way is to use them.

Comment: @chrisheyn As far as I can see, using `pure` everywhere would be fine. Many haskellers still use `return`, especially in `do` blocks, both because of habit (`pure` is more recent) and because they want to remark we are working with a monad. Some instead tend to use `pure`, even when `return` would also work. It's hard to say which one is more idiomatic, but I'd say that using `pure` everywhere would generally be regarded as a matter of "personal style".

Comment: Thank you @chi. I can imagine that using `return` adds more information to the code. That's sounds like a good approach when working with Monads.

Comment: My personal opinion (& speculation) is that, in a parallel universe where `Applicative` was introduced in the base library at the same time as `Monad`, we would not have `return` at all, since that would be redundant. That reasoning could justify a position stating "let's pretend we did the right thing from day one, and consequently behave as if `return` did not exist". Feel free to use `pure` in your code as you wish. As long as you don't become too dogmatic about it, you'll be fine :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every type that is an instance of Monad must have its `return` equal to `pure`.

In particular, since `Applicative` was made a superclass of `Monad`, `return` doesn't need to be defined because by default it is defined to be a synonym of `pure`: see [the definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Monad):

> Furthermore, the Monad and Applicative operations should relate as follows:
>
> - `pure = return`

> Minimal complete definition
>
> ```
> (>>=)
> ```

Notice that the minimal definition only requires `>>=`, not `return`, and the requirement that `pure = return` (which, like all such "laws", cannot be enforced by the language but must hold for all "sane" implementations, otherwise the semantics will not be correct).

But there are types which are Applicative but not a Monad, and therefore have a `pure` but no `return`. [`ZipList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) is the traditional example.